# How do I disable my ASP.NET AJAX ConfirmButtonExtender when page validation fails?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, validationsummary, confirmbutton

I've got a submit button using Microsoft's [ConfirmButton](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) extender to ask "Are you sure?".  However it fires regardless of whether or not the page passes client-side validation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorTextBox1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    ErrorMessage="First name is required"
    Display="Dynamic" />
...
<asp:Button ID="Button1"
    runat="server"
    Text="Submit"
    CausesValidation="True" />
<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtenderButton1"
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Button1"
    ConfirmText="Are you sure?" />
...
<asp:ValidationSummary id="ValidationSummary1"
    runat="server"
    ShowMessageBox="True" />
```

So, if a user leaves a required field blank and clicks the "Submit" button.  She'll see two message boxes:

One for validation...

[ValidationSummary ShowMessageBox http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/8305/validationzn6.gif](http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/8305/validationzn6.gif)

Then one for confirmation ...

[ConfirmButtonExtender http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/678/confirmationam3.gif](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/678/confirmationam3.gif)

(Note: OK and Cancel both just cancel.)

It doesn't make sense for the confirmation to show up if validation fails.  It should be one or the other.  How can I do this?

---

Update:

If I try to use ConfirmOnFormSubmit, then I get this warning:

> Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute
>   'ConfirmOnFormSubmit' is not a valid
>   attribute of element
>   'ConfirmButtonExtender'.

[Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'ConfirmOnFormSubmit' is not a valid attribute of element 'ConfirmButtonExtender'. http://img382.imageshack.us/img382/1391/confirmonformsubmitow3.gif](http://img382.imageshack.us/img382/1391/confirmonformsubmitow3.gif)

Comment: EDIT: According to that website it is valid. Try updating to the latest version and or ignore the intellisense and just see what happens when you post it.

Comment: How did you solve this problem, Zack?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the ConfirmOnFormSubmit is set to TRUE on the ConfirmButtonExtender.

From the [example site](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx):

*ConfirmOnFormSubmit - True if the confirm dialog should wait until just before the form submits to display. This is useful when ASP.NET validators are in use and the confirm should be shown only after all validators pass.*

EDIT: According to that website it is valid. Try [updating to the latest version](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16488) and or ignore the intellisense and just see what happens when you post it.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems like the right answer, but it doesn't work.  I've updated the question.